# Unable to import holidays from fb prophet package

Tags: python, facebook-prophet, python-holidays

Getting error while importing holidays from fb prophet as below. Seems like an intermittent issue.

```
import fbprophet.hdays as hdays_part2

TypeError: This is a python-holidays entity loader class. For entity inheritance purposes please import a class you want to derive from directly: e.g., `from holidays.countries import Entity` or `from holidays.financial import Entity`.

fbprophet version == 0.7.1
```